# How to detect current iframe url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wrote a html code which initializes my iframe with another site.

my domain is for example:

www.mydomain.com/Index.html

in this there's an

```
 <iframe src = "www.anotherdomain.com/pages/firstPage.html"/>
```

I want to detect the complete new src url whenever the iframe gets new one. The iframe text consists links to other pages within the initialised page. Is it possible and legal to get it done ? Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

I guess it goes to cross origin issues but is there a work around for this ?

**Update**

I tried to get the answer by

```
 document.getElementById("myIframeId").src
```

at the frame load event. But it keeps showing the src with which it is initialised. It is not showing the updated src.

```
document.getElementById("myIframeId").contentWindow.location.href
```

gives the Security Error that a http frame is trying to access https in the iframe. Protocols mismatched.

I made the localhost to SSL and used https but the request got blocked. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree with the answers which suggest that you should use "src" to detect the current url of the iframe. It simply doesn't give you the current url - but the url it started with.

The domain has to be from the same origin to use the method of the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myframe').load(function() {
    alert($(this).get(0).contentWindow.location.href);
  }); 
});
```

If the domains are from different origins - but you have access to both (or both are yours), then you can use `window.postMessage` function and `contentWindow` property of iFrame to send the data for the parent to show when a new page loads.

Here is a tutorial on that: http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

And if the domain in the iFrame is completely alien, one approach I can think of is to load that domain in a server side script and get it to render this data with altered links. Now you can call this script inside the iFrame and use `contentWindow.location.href` property whenever it loads.

Comment: Yes you pointed the problem I am facing. Can you check the updated question. Thanks

Comment: I have already given the answers to the matters you have highlighted in your update

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `src` property on an interval to see if it's changed. Here's a function that will do that for you.

```
function watchIframeSRC(iframe, callback, interval) {
    // check every 1 second by default
    if (typeof interval === 'undefined') {
        interval = 1000;
    }
    var src = iframe.src;
    return setInterval(function () {
        // invoke the callback if the src is different
        if (iframe.src !== src) {
            src = iframe.src;
            callback(iframe);
        }
    }, interval);
}

var iframe = document.getElementById('test');

watchIframeSRC(iframe, function (iframe) {
    console.log("iframe src:", iframe.src);
});
```

Comment: I don't want it like that. But however it is not working with the src attribute. Check the updated question. Thanks

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible. And by the sounds of it, you're attempting to do something malicious.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not throw cross origin error.

```
<iframe id="test" src="www.anotherdomain.com/pages/firstPage.html"></iframe>
```

**Javascript:**

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').src);
```

It will alert the src value of iframe.

Also you can set src ynamically.

```
document.getElementById('test').src = "http://www.neuralnetworksolutions.com/resources.php";
```

You can learn more on javascript iframe from http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I worked around to figure out various answers but I was able to do this with the help of YQL and jQuery to make cross domain ajax request. The iFrame won't let me access its inner events. I scraped html from another domain with YQL and got the thing to work. Removed my iFrame and put the scraped html in a div.